# java.util.NoSuchElementException on using queue

Tags: java, exception, database-connection

I am using an if statement and when it runs it shows the exception java.util.NoSuchElementException

The code is shown below

```
if (BackgroundService.pendingQueue != null) {
                logger.error("Here is clear step next 2 ");

            BackgroundService.pendingQueue.remove();

            logger.error("Here is clear step next 3 ");
        }       
        logger.info("BackgroundService.pendingQueue="+BackgroundService.pendingQueue.
size());
        if(BackgroundService.pendingQueue.size() == 0){
            BackgroundService.pendingQueue.clear();
        }
        logger.info("BackgroundService.pendingQueue after task done is ="+BackgroundService.pendingQueue.size());
    }
```

The exeption is show between the "clear step 2" and "clear step 3" statements, on the `BackgroundService.pendingQueue.remove();` statement.
If you have a solution please reply with that solution

Comment: Your code does not have any loop.

Comment: What kind of object is pendingQueue?

Comment: Post your stack trace also

Comment: sorry there is no loop but if statement is throw that exception                 static Queue<collectinfo> pendingQueue;                               pendingQueue = new LinkedList<collectinfo>();

Answer (score 4):

I can imagine your object is a kind of Queue.
If you try to remove an object on an empty queue the exception NoSuchElementException is thrown.

So you need to check if the queue is not empty before trying to remove something:

```
  if(!BackgroundService.pendingQueue.isEmpty()){
    BackgroundService.pendingQueue.remove();
  }
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you

Comment: i have one more exception in uploading file to server that is socket write error and socket recv failed how to fix that can you have an idea how to fix that

Comment: You need to do a new Question on StackOverflow.
Thanks to accept this answer